# using the definition of a supremum

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Could anyone give me some idea's on where to go with this question?
[image: question]

The question ask's to use the definition of a supremum, which i know is:
[image: supremum defn]

Comment: Are you having trouble understanding the definition?

Comment: I don't think so?

Comment: Then see Arthur's answer below.

Answer (score 4):

You are asked to show that $1$ is too small to be the supremum, but $2$ isn't.

In other words, show that $2$ is *an* upper bound of $E$ (not necessarily the *least* upper bound, which is the supremum), while $1$ is not.

The supremum fulfills two properties: in your definition one property relates to $\gamma + \epsilon$, and the other to $\gamma - \epsilon$. The former makes sure that $\gamma$ is large enough, and the latter makes sure that $\gamma$ is small enough. The latter is irrelevant in this specific problem.

Comment: So if I take epsilon=1/5.
x<2+(1/5)
and
x>1+(1/5). Does that work

Comment: @user11015000 For showing that $1$ is too small, picking a single value for $\epsilon$ and a single number from $E$ that demonstrates that $1$ is too small will do. $\epsilon = 1/5$ and $x = 1.3$, for instance. For showing that $2$ is large enough, you have to show that it holds for _any_ $\epsilon>0$, and _any_ $x\in E$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @user11015000 You just need one number, say $\frac{5}{4}$ which belongs to $E$. Now $\gamma$ has to be greater than it by definition, and is hence greater than $1$. Also choose another number, say $\frac{3}{2}$, whose square is greater than $2$. This is an upper bound. So $\gamma$ is less than or equal to it, and hence is less than $2$.

Comment: @Anonymous_original "Now $\gamma$ has to be greater than it, **by definition**" Not according to the given definition above. Sure, it's a consequence that is very easily proven, but it's not by definition. And why are you mixing $\frac32$ into this when $2$ is both directly relevant, and easier?